Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0 using winforms application
I am getting the following error for release whereas it does work locally.
I'm developing a Winforms application on .NET 8.0, using the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0.6 Nuget package.
The package reference is Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.1.5 within Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package. No other reference in project for 5.0.0.0 version.
I get this error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'

I tried using AssemblyRedirects but that didn't work. Expect to work if released the exe to shared drive.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Veera

I have copied the Runtimes folder from bin/release/net8.0-windows, it resolved the issue.

In my case I had just missed copying the Runtimes. Getting them from Debug was OK.
